# how to netboot a Linux VM in VMware server 2.0?

Tags: linux, vmware-server, netboot

Folks,

I am new to using VMware, so please excuse if this is a newbie question.......

How can I netboot a guest Linux virtual machine ?
I'm using VMware server 2.0 running on a Linux host ( Fedora ).

Would appreciate any pointers…..

Cheers !!
S

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is a much simpler answer then you were looking for, but if you configure bridged networking for the guest environment, it will have access to your network as though if it were a physical attached machine and you can follow your (the) normal procedures.

Feel free to elaborate if you have tried and failed to do this, and include a more detailed description of where you are having problems.

Comment: NAT networking also will work, Bridge networking will required IP assigned by DHCP or manually, NAT networking usually comes with DHCP server turned on.